# integration between google colab and github

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am working in google colab with an ipython notebook which I "opened" using the link from github (the notebook is uploaded to Github). Then, in the body of notebook I cloned the repository to have an access to a library from a repository. I want to modify this library occasionaly, e.g. write a new function. I noticed that even though I can view the code for the files in this library, and even modify the code of this library in colab, e.g. write a new function, I can't import this function in my ipython notebook. What is the best way to solve this problem?

I tried to modify the library on my local computer, then upload these files to github. But when I try to pull the files from the repository on ipython notebook on colab using `!git pull origin master` it says that all files are already up to date. Even a new added function is present in a library in colab - I still cannot import the function.

I also tried to close and "open" again this notebook in colab using the github link (to be able to run a cell with `!git clone` again - I deleted these files from the notebook in colab using `%rm -rf` beforehand). Colab still doesn't see the function defined in github.

I'm new to git and colab. Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

first point out to the location in drive as

```
%cd /content/drive/My Drive/dir1
```

then clone the directory you want, e.g.,

```
!git clone https://github.com/KaiDMML/FakeNewsNet
```

on refreshing the drive, you will find the cloned directory in the drive.

**Remember to connect to the drive first** before all these steps
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll check it out later